# Import Scala object based on value of commandline argument

Tags: scala, import

Lets say I have the following structure:

```
src
 - main 
  - scala
   - model
     - One.scala 
     - Two.scala
   - main
     - Test.scala
```

where Test.scala extends App and takes in a parameter:

```
object Test extends App {

val param: String = args.head  

// Based on param, I want to use either One or Two?

}
// sbt run Two
```

How do i use definitions in either `One.scala` or `Two.scala` depending on the runtime value of `param`.

Appreciate any/all inputs..

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `One` and `Two` share some common interface, choose the instance of this interface at runtime, then import the members of the instance:

```
trait CommonInterface {
  def foo(): Unit
}

object One extends CommonInterface { def foo() = println("1") }
object Two extends CommonInterface { def foo() = println("2") }

object Main extends App {
  // check args etc...
  val ci = if (args(0) == "one") One else Two
  import ci._
  // do something with `foo` here
  foo()
}
```